# jQuery AutoComplete JSON in CakePHP

Tags: jquery, json, cakephp, jquery-autocomplete

I'm trying to make jQuery AutoComplete JSON data with CakePHP. My code actually WORKs. It shows the autocompletion as expected, but it fails on:

1. the selected item doesn't show up in the searchbox once we select it (blank).
2. the 'No result' doesn't show up if the data does not exist.

Here's the code:

//**search action of my Customer controller**

```
function search(){

    $this->Customer->recursive = -1;

    $customers = $this->Customer->find('all', array(
        'conditions'=>array('Customer.nama LIKE'=>$this->params['url']['q'].'%'),
        'fields'=>array('id', 'name', 'telp', 'address'))
    );

    $this->set('customers', $customers);

    Configure::write('debug', 0);
    $this->layout = 'ajax';             
}
```

//**my search.ctp**

```
<?php

if(!empty($customers)) {

    $data = array();

    foreach ($customers as $customer){
        $data[] = $customer['Customer'];
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
else echo 'No result';

?>
```

//**my js file**

```
$().ready(function () {

    $("#search-txtbox").autocomplete("/customers/search",
        {
            parse: function(data){ 
                var parsed = [];
                for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    parsed[i] = {
                        data: data[i],
                        value: data[i].name //the search item
                    };
                }
                return parsed;
            },
            formatItem: function (row, i, max) {
                var str = row.name + ' (Telp: '+ row.telp +')' + '<br />';
                str += row.address;
                return str;                     
            },
            formatResult: function (row) {
                return row.name;
            },
            minChars: 2,
            max: 0,
            width: 224,
            scrollHeight: 420,
            dataType: 'json'
        }
    );
});
```

Please help me modify the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the plugin you're using has been deprecated in favor of [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete), and I'd highly recommend using it instead (better support from the community, updates, etc.). However, if for some reason you have to use that plugin, here are your issues:

1. This is poorly documented (if it is documented at all), but it looks like the `parse` function must return an object with a `result` property that gets inserted into the `input` element. So you should just have to modify you're parse function to add that property:

   ```
   parse: function(data){ 
       var parsed = [];
       for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
           parsed[i] = {
               data: data[i],
               value: data[i].name, //the search item
               result: data[i].result
           };
       }
       return parsed;
   },
   ```
2. I'm not sure where you want "No result" to show up, but you could slightly modify your PHP code and show a message inside the `parse` function:

   **PHP**

   ```
   $data = array();

   foreach ($customers as $customer){
       $data[] = $customer['Customer'];
   }

   echo json_encode($data);
   ```

   **JavaScript**

   ```
   parse: function(data){ 
       var parsed = [];
       for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
           parsed[i] = {
               data: data[i],
               value: data[i].name, //the search item
               result: data[i].name
           };
       }
       if (!parsed.length) { // <-- Do something with the "No Results" message.
           $("body").append("no results");
       }
       return parsed;
   },
   ```

Sorry I can't provide a working example. If you want an example using the jQueryUI widget, I'd be happy to provide one.